# tablas html con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de hacer que esas lineas no lleguen hasta el final ??
Pongo mi código:

```
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Equipo</th>
        <th>Comienzo de la conexion</th>
        <th>Fin de la conexion</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($equipos2 as $equipo2): ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="100"><?=$equipo2->hostname?></td>
        <td width="210"><?=$equipo2->fecha_inicio?></td>
        <td width="154"><?=$equipo2->fecha_fin?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="eliminar.php?IDregistro=<?=$equipo2->IDregistro?>" colspan="2">
                <img src="papelera.png" width="30" title="Eliminar conexión"></img>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Te llegaran al final porque tendras una fila entera y eso va de punta a punta, en la clase de la table ponle un container ja veras como no te llegan limitalo a alguna columna o a un contenedor.

Comment: Si ya marcas los width de las columnas (cosa que **no** recomiendo en bootstrap) entonces súmalos y pon un width un poco mayor a la tabla que sea esa suma como mínimo y así harás la tabla clavada a lo que quieres (pero no creo que sea demasiado responsive y saldrá de madre cuando el dispositivo tenga un ancho menor que el width de la tabla).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner tu tabla dentro de un `<div class="container>` esta clase creara un margen.
De otra manera puedes poner un `<div class="row">` y darle a tu tabla una clase `class="col-número del 1 al 12"`, esto es por que la cuadricula de bootstrap de divide en 12 columnas, asi puedes hacer mas ancho o estrecho un `div`. Estas dos opciones las puedes combinar sin problema.
Quedando algo asi:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <table class="table col-10">
        <tr>
            <th>Equipo</th>
            <th>Comienzo de la conexion</th>
            <th>Fin de la conexion</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach ($equipos2 as $equipo2): ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"><?=$equipo2->hostname?></td>
            <td width="210"><?=$equipo2->fecha_inicio?></td>
            <td width="154"><?=$equipo2->fecha_fin?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="eliminar.php?IDregistro=<?=$equipo2->IDregistro?>" colspan="2">
                    <img src="papelera.png" width="30" title="Eliminar conexión"></img>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </table>
    <div>
 <div>
```